# Django unittest m2m instance no create pk?

Tags: python, django

I am creating unittest working with M2M model.

`models.py`

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from geoposition.fields import GeopositionField
from model_controller.models import AbstractModelController

from soken_web.apps.customers.models import Customer


class House(models.Model):
    ...
    customers = models.ManyToManyField(Customer, related_name='houses')  # Use M2M in case family member do same thing
```

First test case runs fine.
But the second one it is not.

`tests.py`

```
import copy

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from model_mommy import mommy
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase, APIClient

from soken_web.apps.customers.models import Customer
from soken_web.apps.houses.models import House


class HouseTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.soken_staff = mommy.make(User, username='spearhead')
        self.customer = mommy.make(Customer)
        self.data = {
            'address_line_1': "testing data",
            'address_line_2': "testing data",
            'prefecture': "testing data",
            'town': "testing data",
            'city': "testing data",
            'building': "testing data",
            'postal_code': "10330",
            'location': "13.747288, 100.528155",
            'customers': self.customer.id,
        }

    def test_create_house(self):
        self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.soken_staff)
        res = self.client.post(reverse('api:house-list'), data=self.data)
        self.assertEqual(201, res.status_code)
        self.assertEqual(1, res.data.get('id'))  # Confirm that mobile known ID

    def test_update_house(self):
        user = User.objects.create(username='aoc')
        self.client.force_authenticate(user=user)
        data = copy.deepcopy(self.data)
        data['created_user'] = self.soken_staff
        data['updated_user'] = self.soken_staff
        house = House.objects.create(**data)
        house.customers.add(self.customer)
        house.refresh_from_db()
        patch = {
            "town": "MBK",
        }
        res = self.client.patch(reverse('api:house-detail', kwargs={'pk': house.id}), data=patch)
        self.assertEqual(200, res.status_code)
```

**Background:**
In the `test_update_house`. I have to create the sample and then `patch` it. The reason why I do not use `model_mommy` because in the class attribute it has `GeopositionField` which is not supported by `model_mommy`

**Problem:**
Although I explicitly `.create()` it and then do `refresh_from_db()`
ORM raises me the error.
`ValueError: "<House: House object>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

Comment: You may need to save the `House` object before refreshing from db. ie, `house = House.objects.create(**data); house.customers.add(self.customer); house.save(); house.refresh_from_db()`

Comment: My bad. You're right. I must not assign the customer at the very beginning. I was confused with the `test_create_house`. Thank you very much.

Comment: calling `house.save()` after `house.customers.add()` actually shouldn't be necessary in many-to-many relations as seen in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/). Did that fix your problem?

Comment: I did create house without `customer` in the kwargs. Then `house.customers.add(..)`. Yes, you are right. I did not call `house.save()`